# Rational function with constants

Tags: calculus

I've recently been introduced to calculus and ran into a rational function that seems to be somewhat complicated for my understanding, which is shown in the form: $$f(x) = \frac{(x−a)(x−b)}{(c−a)(c−b)} \cdot a + \frac{(x−b)(x−c)}{(a−b)(a−c)} \cdot b + \frac{(x−a)(x−c)}{(b−a)(b−c)} \cdot c$$

Bearing in mind that when $f(a) = b$, $f(b) = c$ and $f(c) = a$ due to substitution.

However, the part I don't understand is the simplification of the equation into the quadratic form as follows:

$$\frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}[(a-b)a+(b-c)b+(c-a)c]x^2+  [(a-b)b^2+(b-c)c^2+(c-a) a^2]x + [(a-b)a^{2}+(b-c)b^{2}c+(c-a) ac^2]$$

Based on my algebraic knowledge, I know that the factorization formula is $x^2+(a+b)x + ab$

My question is how did the coefficients and rearranged dominator of the original equation come about?  Can anyone detail it for me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Lookup the [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html). `I know that the factorization formula is x^2+(a+b)x + ab` That's only true if the quadratic is known to have roots $-a,-b\,$, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{(x−a)(x−b)}{(c−a)(c−b)} \cdot a + \frac{(x−b)(x−c)}{(a−b)(a−c)} \cdot b + \frac{(x−a)(x−c)}{(b−a)(b−c)} \cdot c 
\\&= \frac{(x−a)(x−b)}{(a-c)(b-c)} \cdot a + \frac{(x−b)(x−c)}{(a−b)(a−c)} \cdot b - \frac{(x−a)(x−c)}{(a-b)(b−c)} \cdot c \\
&= \frac{g(x)} {(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}\end{align}
where $$g(x)=(x−a)(x−b) \cdot a(a-b) + (x−b)(x−c) \cdot b (b-c) - (x−a)(x−c) \cdot c (a-c)$$

The coefficient of $x^2$ of $g(x)$ is just

$$a(a-b)+b(b-c)-c(a-c)$$

The coefficient of $x$ of $g(x)$ is just

\begin{align}&-(a+b)a(a-b)-(b+c)b(b-c)+(a+c)c(a-c) \\&=-a(a^2-b^2)-b(b^2-c^2)+c(a^2-c^2)\\&=-a^3+ab^2-b^3+bc^2-c^3+ca^2\\
&=b^2(a-b)+c^2(b-c)+a^2(c-a)\end{align}

Try to compute coefficient of $1$ of $g(x)$

Comment: Having calculated the last coefficient I had reached;


ab.a(a−c)+bc.b(b−c)−ac.c(a−c)=a2b(a−b)+b2c(b−c)−ac2(a−c)


Which I believe along with the other coefficients should be simplified to;

(a+b+c)x2+(b2+c2+a2)x+(a2b+b2c−ac2)

Nevertheless, when I used horner's method to evaluate the polynomials it didn't seem to support the author's claim , whereas the equation is supposed to end up with the three terms. a, b, c.

So am I doing anything wrong? thank you once more.

Comment: In general $\frac{AD+BE+CF}{ABC} \neq D+E+F$.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the names of the quadratic $dx^2 + e x + f,$ we are saying
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
a^2 & a & 1 \\
b^2 & b & 1 \\
c^2 & c & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
d \\
e \\
f
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
b \\
c \\
a
\end{array}
\right)
$$
We just invert the 3 by 3 matrix (Vandermonde type). [The determinant is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) in $a,b,c.$ Indeed, the determinant is $( a -b)  ( b - c)  ( a - c)$

The determinant times the inverse matrix is

$$
W =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
b-c & c-a & a-b \\
c^2 -b^2 & a^2 - c^2 & b^2 - a^2 \\
bc(b-c) & ca(c-a) & ab(a-b)
\end{array}
\right)
$$